# Docusign UserInfo endpoint returns 401 Unauthorized when access token is provided

Tags: docusignapi

I am integrating my API backend with DocuSign in order to send and retrieve envelopes. I am using the JWT Grant flow.
[Authentication options](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/)

In the DocuSign development environment, I am able to retrieve an access token using the JWT flow and the Docusign C# SKD.
I need to then call the `oauth/userinfo` endpoint in order to retrieve the base_uri field to use for making calls to Docusign.

When I make a GET request to https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo, including the access token in the Authorization header as `Bearer <access_token>`, I receive a 401 Unauthorized response, and this message in the body:

```
{
    "error": "internal_server_error",
    "reference_id": "<some GUID>"
}
```

I have tried this using curl, Postman and the C# SDK and all give the same result.

Curl syntax:
`curl --header "Authorization: Bearer <access token>" https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo`

[user-info endpoint documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/)

[JWT flow (step 4)](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/)

As far as I can see, I appear to be calling the API according to the documentation and I have set up the account with an RSA key pair which is required for system integrations (created within the Docusign admin portal).

Can anyone think of a reason this could be happening?

Comment: Are you making sure you are using the access token within 1 hour of creation?

Comment: Yes, I am using it immediately afterwards (within a minute). I just thought that I might need to add another scope when granting consent. I will try this shortly.
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/scopes/

Comment: Adding extra scopes didn't make a difference.
I found in the following page at the bottom of the pre-requisites, that "Application Authentication Grant" needs to be associated with one of the accounts and enabled. I can't see where to do this in the admin portal. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/admin101/application-auth/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the C# SDK as you mentioned, you can call this endpoint using the same SDK if you have a valid token.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/c-sharp/reference/

```
public OAuth.UserInfo GetUserInfo(string accessToken);
```

You can confirm that your token is valid by trying to use it for other API calls.
A token from the developer account should be useful to make this call in the developer account only. If you need this for production (typically reason to need the **base_uri**) then you have to call it with account.docusign.com not account-d.docusign.com.

Comment: reference_id GUID can be used to trace this issue on our back-end if you want to send it to us.

Comment: Thank you for the link @inbar-gazit. I think I might be getting the access token incorrectly. I am using the C# SDK method RequestJWTApplicationToken as I thought this was the one to use for system integrations. Should I be using RequestJWTUserToken and impersonating a user for a system integration?

Comment: yes, the former is only for specific actions that only ISVs that are registered with DocuSign can use. You need the latter (RequestJWTUserToken)

Answer (score 0):

I have now been able to get the base_uri from UserInfo endpoint using the RequestJWTUserToken method in the C# SDK. Using this token allows me to hit the REST API endpoint.
Both methods appear to hit the same `oauth/token` endpoint and use the same grant type, only RequestJWTUserToken includes the "sub" claim for the userId.